# Where can I find data on current space agency contracts?

Tags: nasa, reference-request, research, esa

I'm trying to compile a list of current space contracts held by NASA, the CSA, and any other space-related agency so that I can get a feel for what the most heavily researched areas are.

What are some resources that might list contracts like these?

Comment: This is not a good question for this site. List questions are generally perceived as off-topic, as are overly broad questions. This falls into both categories.

Comment: My feeling is that this is a reference request. It isn't a list that will be long or hard to maintain, as it won't change much. It doesn't seem too broad either as it only asks where to find this information, not what the information is.

Answer (score 4):

This [website](https://prod.nais.nasa.gov/cgibin/npdv/npdv.cgi) has access to "all current NASA contracts."  The organization seems kinda goofy (it seems to be a way for politicians to find out how much NASA is spending in their district) but if you keep drilling down you can find the info.  for example, there is the 28 billion dollars going to Boeing.  But fear not, that is the total, this year is only 1.8 billion.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As a starting point, for the part of the question aimed at "any other space-related agency" this link takes you to the European Space Agencies tender announcement site:

http://emits.sso.esa.int/emits/owa/emits.main

It lists up an coming contracts and those that are currently open for competition. Its quite hard to find out what contracts have been placed with whom until some time after the event.

Sticking with this site for the moment, you can see by picking any individual item in the Open Invitation To Tender list that it identifies amounts of money and which ESA department. Whilst this responds to the request for lists of contracts you can see that you are right down in the weeds and there is too much to digest.

You might be more interested in a year-ahead or multi-year workplan. I'll add one when I next come accross one.